# Not getting input from Django form

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using Django's forms.py method for building a form, but am not getting any data when trying to user request.POST.get('value') on it. For every print statement that gave a response,
I put a comment next to the command with whatever it returned in the terminal.

Additionally, I do not understand what the `action = "address"` is meant for in the form. Finally, the csrf verification was not working and kept returning `CSRF verification failed` so I disabled it, but if anyone knows how to get this working I would appreciate it.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Enter name:', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def blank(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        get = request.POST.get
        print(f"get: {get}") # get: <bound method MultiValueDict.get of <QueryDict: {}>>

        print(f"your_name: {request.POST.get('your_name')}") # your_name: None


        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            your_name = form.cleaned_data["your_name"]
            print(f"your_name cleaned: {your_name}")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'blank.html', {'form': form})
```

blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For whatever reason the form is NOT valid. You need to display or print the error messages.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages